# Ecryptfs input/output error

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

Recently my primary workstation OS "Linux Ubuntu" failed to boot and has since become irrecoverable, however the encrypted home directory is still intact but i cannot decrypt as it keeps giving me this error

```
root@Linux:/# ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/11132/task/11132/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/11132/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/11742/task/11742/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/11742/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/media/USER/MOUNTED_DRIVE/home/.ecryptfs/USER/.Private/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[long encrypted name]/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[long encrypted name]/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[long encrypted name]’: Input/output error
find: ‘/media/USER/MOUNTED_DRIVE/home/.ecryptfs/USER/.Private/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[long encrypted name]/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[long encrypted name]/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[long encrypted name]’: Input/output error
```

All of my college stuff is on it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it is "still intact"? "All of my college stuff is on it" - Please tell me you have backups.

Comment: it is intact, I can still access all of the OS and programs but my home dir was encrypted

Comment: What happens if you try to mount it? `sudo mount -t ecryptfs /path/to/encrypted/dir /mount/point`?

Comment: It asks for passphrase, cipher, key bytes, enable plaintext passthrough , enable filename encryption, and filename encryption key (FNEK) sig

Comment: Enter your details then. Passphrase, cipher and key bytes should be known to you (if not, leave defaults for cipher and key bytes). Plaintext passthrough is usually the default. Filename encryption depends on what you set up. Can you see the filenames of the encrypted files? If not, enter `Y`es. The FNEK sig you can just hit return on that question.

Comment: it mounts but I can't `cd` into it without root and `ls` just shows the files and structure of the original drive

Comment: The root thing is normal. I don't know by memory right now how to mount it in userspace, iirc the `-t` switch of mount needs root permissions. What do you mean by "original drive"? Try running `ls` as root too. If the mount was successful this should work.

Comment: did not decrypt, acts like symlink

Answer (score 0):

Was not supplying path.

Solved by running:

```
ecryptfs-recover-private /media/UUID/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Pravate
```